# Android incompeted download file

Tags: android, download, mp3

I try to download audio from a URL. I use following sample download manager code from Github https://github.com/folee/Download_Mgr

My problem is If i cancel download, Incomplete mp3 file still there in SDcard. How can i remove Incomplete mp3 files?

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(DownloadValues.Actions.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE_ACTION);

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_continue:
            // mDownloadManager.continueTask(mPosition);
            downloadIntent.putExtra(DownloadValues.TYPE, DownloadValues.Types.CONTINUE);
            downloadIntent.putExtra(DownloadValues.URL, url);
            mContext.startService(downloadIntent);

            mViewHolder.continueButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mViewHolder.pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_pause:
            // mDownloadManager.pauseTask(mPosition);
            downloadIntent.putExtra(DownloadValues.TYPE, DownloadValues.Types.PAUSE);
            downloadIntent.putExtra(DownloadValues.URL, url);
            mContext.startService(downloadIntent);

            mViewHolder.continueButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mViewHolder.pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_delete:
            // mDownloadManager.deleteTask(mPosition);
            downloadIntent.putExtra(DownloadValues.TYPE, DownloadValues.Types.DELETE);
            downloadIntent.putExtra(DownloadValues.URL, url);
            mContext.startService(downloadIntent);

            removeItem(url);
            break;
        }
    }
```

my file bath :

```
 public class ConfigUtils {

 public static void InitPath(Context ctx) {
    File temFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    if (temFile != null && temFile.canWrite() && Util.getAvailableExternalMemorySize() > 0) {
        IMG_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DL_Mgr/Image/";
        FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DL_Mgr/Downloads/";
    }
    else {
        IMG_PATH = ctx.getFilesDir() + "/Image/";
        FILE_PATH = ctx.getFilesDir() + File.separator;
    }

    new File(IMG_PATH).mkdirs();
    new File(FILE_PATH).mkdirs();
    Log.i(TAG, "IMG_PATH-->" + IMG_PATH + "\n FILEPATH-->" + FILE_PATH);
}
```

}

I use this code for delete temp files but not work

```
 case R.id.btn_delete:

            File tempFile = new File(ConfigUtils.FILE_PATH + "filename".toString());
            if(tempFile.exists()) {
                tempFile.delete();
            }
```

But it not work
 EDIT:
WORKING CODE: (If download mp3 temp file remane like : "sample.mp3.download"

so ichanged code like this it work fine

```
 File tempFile = new File(ConfigUtils.FILE_PATH + filename +".download".toString());
            if(tempFile.exists()) {
                tempFile.delete();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Before downloading starts. You must know where you are saving the file. So probably a absolute path or Uri pointing to a file in sdcard
  that you are giving to Download manager to store your file at.
- Incase of cancel. create a file object from that uri or absolute path and call delete on file object if exists. 
  Something like this

  ```
  File tempFile = new File(uri.toString());
  if(tempFile.exists()) {
      tempFile.delete();
  }
  ```

This should be simple. Google it out

Comment: Check i changed my code but it not work.. still i have "sample.mp3.download" in my SDcard

Comment: @Mullinsangebn ConfigUtils.FILE_PATH.toString(). Does this contain the complete absolute path of your file ?. If yes please check and log the value of tempFile.exists() call

Comment: also FILEPATH seems to be a directory not a file. you have to check whether your file object isDirectory. If yes you have to iterate for every file the directory and create file object of exh of them and delete them individually

Comment: ConfigUtils.FILE_PATH is only download folder name so i added File tempFile = new File(ConfigUtils.FILE_PATH +"filename".toString());

Comment: this one also not work... still i have a temp file called "1.mp3.download".  This one work fine File tempFile = new File(ConfigUtils.FILE_PATH+"1.mp3.download".toString());  we need also filname with ".download" now it work